# method to find out reason behind CSS behaviour

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools

I would like to know why some CSS properties are not applied as expected to html elements. I am not trying to fix a particular issue but I am looking for a general approach to be followed.

[inspector screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJ7qa.png)

As seen in the above screenshot, I have a media query to be applied when the width is equal to or exceeds 40 rem.

But the width that I want to be applied to the plan class is 30% which is not applied but instead a width of 100% defined as a property of the plan class is still applied.

Though the inspector shows the property crossed out, is there any tool to find out the reason it is not applied?

Comment: You actually have the `computed` tab to see what set the actual style, and probably the fact that the default `.plan` styles are **after** the media query makes it to apply the style

Comment: can you please expound on that?

Comment: You should move the media queries to the end of your CSS

Comment: Yes sir. I found out that is the reason. What I want to know is, is there any tool in chrome or any other browser which would show (some cooment or tooltip) why a style is striken through and not applied?

Comment: Yes, the `computed` tab lists each style and for each style you can see the list of values sorted by priority

Comment: If this was posted as an answer instead of a comment, would have accepted it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

The list of styles is shown in reverse order of how they are applied.

You can see that the top set of styles is the `style` property, and it is empty.

The next one is `.plan` and sets `width: 100%`.

The next one is `.plan` inside the media query, and is overridden because of the previous one.

---

You can see a simple view, but focused on specific properties, but looking in the Computed tab and clicking the triangle next to the property you are interested in to expand the list.

---

See [The Cascade](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade) in the CSS specification for an explanation about what order properties are applied in.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot. So if I understand correctly, if a media query condition is met, in this case, width exceeds 40 rem the styles specified would be applied. But if there is another style down the line which applies to the same element, it would be applied without considering the fact that a media query style has been applied since its condition was satisfied?

Comment: It does *consider* the previous style (although the fact it was in a media query has no impact on the rules) and the later rule with the same specificity wins.